# How does Redis Streams handle using up all available memory?

Tags: redis

How will Redis handle an XADD when all available memory is used?  Will the oldest item(s) be deleted from the stream and the new item added?  Will the old item still exist in the AOF file from when it was added?  Will it just throw an error and not add the new item?  What should I expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Streams are data structures like all others, so Redis will respect the `maxmemory` and `maxmemory-policy` in case of RAM pressure. Depending on the policy, new write requests will be denied, or existing keys (streams or not) will be evicted.

Read more about this at https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache

Comment: So the whole stream will be evicted when `maxmemory` is reached? If so, that's not very useful. Perhaps it really evicts individual items from the stream?